# "status code 403" Error while creating file using Mule 4 google drive connector

Tags: mulesoft, mule-component, mule4, mule-esb, mule-connector

I have to upload images to google drive through mule integration. I'm facing trouble with `<google-drive:file-content>` connector. Can someone help me or direct me a tutorial relates to it?

This is the error message while I tried to connect to the google drive

```
Message               : Request returned status code 403
Element               : imageuploaderFlow/processors/4 @ 
imageuploader:imageuploader.xml:39 (Create media file)
Element DSL           : <google-drive:create-media-file doc:name="Create media file" doc:id="hhhhhjhj" config-ref="Google_Drive_Connector_Config" contentType="application/octet-stream">
<google-drive:file-content><![CDATA[
#[payload.parts.image.content write "application/octet-stream"]
]]></google-drive:file-content>
</google-drive:create-media-file>
Error type            : GOOGLE-DRIVE:CLIENT_ERROR
FlowStack             : at imageuploaderFlow(imageuploaderFlow/processors/4 @ imageuploader:imageuploader.xml:39 (Create media file))
```

- Google Drive Connector Config
  scopes: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file

connector xml snippet

```
<google-drive:create-media-file doc:name="Create media file" doc:id="ac59e7fe-e615-fggh-9473-2we5cd73ecb7" config-ref="Google_Drive_Connector_Config" contentType="application/octet-stream">
            <google-drive:file-content ><![CDATA[#[payload.parts.image.content write "application/octet-stream"]]]></google-drive:file-content>
        </google-drive:create-media-file>
```

The version of the Google Drive connector is 1.0.1

Comment: Are you able to complete the OAuth dance? you are getting `403` it means that the google client do not have enough permission

Comment: @HarshankBansal yes I completed the OAuth dance. The error message does not give me much detail here. Not sure how to fix  it.

Comment: Can you share the cofig? There must be an option somewhere of adding scope. Can you tell what scopes have you used in that config?

Comment: @HarshankBansal  I added both https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive  and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file to the scope. Other than that I gave consumer key and secret, resource owner id, callback path, authorize path, and external callback url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you have [Enabled the Google Drive API](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/enable-api) in your project. Not enabling this also raises a 403 error. Also, mostly, Google API sends pretty clear message when you do something wrong. You can access the detailed HTTP response using `error.errorMessage.payload` and headers using `error.errorMessage.attributes.headers`

Comment: I added config xml and the version is 1.0.1

Comment: I'm confused here. I don't have API key. what I did is I created OAuth 2.0 Client IDs and get it's id and secret to my config file. Then I added a user (resource owner).  I gave to call back path as /callback and authorize path as /authorize. After my project launched first time access the url  /authorize with resourceid and give credentials to the google account and grant permisssion to the app. I got response as "Successfully retrieved access token". Then I sent a request through postman with image attached I got this error. Is there any other thing I have to do other than this process?

Comment: @ZuseeWeekin Apart from the steps you mentioned above you will have to enable Google drive API for your project. Add an error handler in your flow, and log the error.errorMessage.payload, that is the only way to find the error that you are facing.

Comment: I created an API key for the project but to enable the project, it's still not visible under the library which means it does not grant access.  To grant access when I go to the endpoint service page, my API name is not visible there. Do you have any idea  reason for it?

Comment: If you don't see the API in the list, that means you don't have enough permission to activate it. You will need to contact your admin.

Comment: yes but I'm using my own google account here. So I should have access to it.  When I go to grant permission 'Endpoint service' page my API is not visible there too. I feel like I have missed some more steps.

Comment: You can try this. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/enable-drive-api
Or you can follow my advice to check the error message. That message will have a direct link to your project where you will see the enable button.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I fixed it. I did a silly mistake that's why it drags this much. But the issue was with enabling API as you suggested.